# Triggering site in new tab or window in Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I use autocrat to mail merge legal documents with a database in Google Sheet. Autocrat does instantaneously trigger when a Google Form is submitted, which is great, but I also require the task to perform automatically. Through some searching, I learnt that a modified Google Form link can submit Google Forms with pre=filled answer.

**This is where I am stuck.**

I have set up (or I think I have) the script in Google Sheet to `onChange (Insert_row, edit)`. I'd like that to trigger a new window or tab to open, going to the modified Google Form link, thereby triggering the form, which then triggers autocrat, then I can have my documents mail merged automatically.

This is the code I am using, which isn't working.

```
function openWindow(url) {
  window.open('url', '_blank');
  window.focus();
}
```

**Is this a coding error, or is this a limitation within Google Script?** Most of the codes I found involves using a button and then clicking it, I also read that there are browser limitations for auto pop-ups.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Bear in mind that this site has specific participation guidelines that are very differently to those that are common in online forums. Regarding question, they should be straight to the point and include only information about your efforts to find the answer or solution by yourself. Reference [ask].

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

While Google Sheets and Google Forms use HTML, JavaScript and related things to work, there are some restrictions. See the guides to learn about what could be done.

## Explanation

JavaScript window object doesn't work on your script because the code on .gs files runs on Google servers (server-side) not on the user browser (client-side).

See [Dialogs and Sidebars on Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs) to learn the basics about how to show a dialog.